# Is it possible to have this many values in a #define and if so why doesn't this code work

Tags: c

```
#define SVALUES (1.2, 2.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.2, 2.7, 3.3, 3.9, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8, 8.2, 10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 33, 39, 47, 56, 68, 82)
#define CVALUES (10,15,22,33,47,68)

if(rA == SVALUES){
    printf("Ra is a standard value.\n");
}
if(rA != SVALUES){
    printf("Ra is not a standard value.\n");
}

if(rB == SVALUES){
    printf("Rb is a standard value.\n");
}
if(rB != SVALUES){
    printf("Rb is not a standard value.\n");
}

if(c == CVALUES){
    printf("c is a standard value.\n");
}
if(c != CVALUES){
    printf("c is not a standard value.\n");
}
```

Comment: Replace `SVALUES` in your code with `(1.2, 2.2, 1.5,....)` and tell if it is a legal C and what it does if it is. Hint: [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: What would you expect this to do: `if(c == (10,15,22,33,47,68)) {` ?

Comment: no way I'm aware of to "shortcut" these comparisons. Need to put all those values in arrays (hardcoded, read from file, etc), loop over the arrays and compare each one. [Be mindful of the pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) associated with doing exact comparisons on floating point values. Since the values are ordered, you could implement a binary search algorithm, but there's so few values here, not worth it IMO.

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
#define CVALUES (10,15,22,33,47,68)

if(c == CVALUES){
```

is the same as

```
if(c == (10,15,22,33,47,68)){
```

and the `(10,15,22,33,47,68)` will give the result 68 due to the way the comma operator works.

So the code is really

```
if(c == 68){
```

which is most likely not what you expect.

If you want to check if a specific value is in an array, you need a loop to iterate over the array elements.

Something like:

```
int CVALUES[] = {10,15,22,33,47,68};
int found = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(CVALUES)/sizeof(CVALUES[0]); ++i)
{
    if (c == CVALUES[i])
    {
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if (found == 1)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: how would you do this in c not c++

Comment: @jimbo this is actually valid C code (and valid C++ code)